# Is rank of $E_p:y^2=x^3+px$($p$ is a prime number) still open?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

In 'Rational Points on Elliptic Curves' by Silverman and Tate, it is stated that the rank of the elliptic curve $E_p: y^2 = x^3 + px (p \equiv 1 \mod 8)$ is **believed to be either $0$ or $2$**. I am surprised that such a fundamental elliptic curve still has open problems associated with it.

My question is:

Is this problem still unresolved? Additionally, if we assume the validity of the **parity conjecture**, does this problem remain open?

Comment: Elliptic curves are complicated objects. It can even be difficult to decide whether they have a solution in integers. The smallest solution can be huge. So , I would not be surprised if "easy" statements are still open. But I am not an expert in this topic.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this conjecture (why can't the rank be 4?), but it's certainly open, even assuming the parity conjecture. It might be possible to show that it's "almost always" true, i.e. that $E_p$ has rank 0 for a set of primes of Dirichlet density 1.